# killing process on prod with shell give segmentation fault

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that executes this line of code:

```
#!/bin/bash -f
echo "killing existing process on port 8080..."
kill $(netstat -aon | grep 8080 | awk '{print $5}')
```

And when I execute the script, it says:

```
killing existing process on port 8080...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If I copy and paste the line of `kill` to the terminal and run it, the terminal got shut down.

I am running from the git's shell from a windows machine, but not sure if this will make any difference.

Comment: Try to remove `-f` from first line of script

Comment: @jamesdeath123: Maybe the process being killed does have a signal handler for the SIGTERM (which you are sending), but due to a bug in the implementation of this signal handler, it runs on SIGSEGV?

Answer (score 0):

`kill` was a command on linux, although in `git bash windows` we could see it, but I guess it cannot handle signal well on different OS.

If not insist on, I suggest you to use `taskkill`, something like follows:

```
#!/bin/bash -f
echo "killing existing process on port 8080..."
taskkill //F //PID $(netstat -aon | grep 8080 | awk '{print $5}')
```

Comment: The script will be deployed to a linux server though, don't think taskkill is available? Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: So, this is just an issue about "develop on windows" but "deploy on linux"?

Comment: Then, 1. if use shell, use `uname -a` to parse os, then do different actions. 2. If could use something like python, directly use the api python afford which could cross platform. 3. If not want to have any difference, then you should use virtualbox, or docker.

Comment: yeah I will do that for a web app, but this is just to run a script.. I will probably use a python or js to do it.